# Advanced Custom Fields loop behaviour

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a page with 3 custom fields. For each of these fields I need to use a template. So what I do is

```
<?php if( have_rows('page_block') ):?>
    <?php while ( have_rows('page_block') ) : the_row();?>
        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'content_block' ):?>
            <?php get_template_part("content-block");?>
        <?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'slider' ):?>
            <?php get_template_part("slider"); ?>
        <?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'news_block' ):?>
            <?php get_template_part("news-block"); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
....
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that only the first two fields are displayed on the page. So when the order of the fields is

1. Content-block
2. Slider
3. News-block

Only the content-block and slider are shown. When I place the slider at the bottom, only the content-block and news-block are displayed.

Any idea what the problem might be?

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that when I echo the get_row_layout(), I get the names of all 3 fields.

```
<?php if( have_rows('page_block') ):?>
    <?php while ( have_rows('page_block') ) : the_row();?>
        <?php echo get_row_layout(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Displays content_block slider news_block

Comment: Have you echoed out what is being returned in have_rows without the conditionals? If it isn't displaying, it's either because the data isn't coming back or your conditions are messed up. I would write all of your logic out in a single php block until you've identified the issue.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention that. When I echo the get_row_layout(), I get the names of all 3 fields.

Comment: Can you please add that to your question. Just copy and paste the command and the result so people can see that

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The slider template was using a WP_Query and I had to add `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` to fix the problem. I think the query broke the loop or something like that. Either way, problem was fixed by adding said line!